# Json parsing failed _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String

Tags: flutter

I want to parse this API response:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "image": "https://asasas"
    },
    {
      "image": "https://xxzx"
    }
  ]
}
```

model :

```
class SliderModel {
  final String count;
  final List<Result> results;

  SliderModel({this.count, this.results});

  factory SliderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list = parsedJson['results'] as List;
    List<Result> imagesList = list.map((i) => Result.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return SliderModel(
      count: parsedJson['count'],
      results: imagesList
    );
  }
}

class Result {
  final String image;

  Result({this.image});

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Result(
      image: parsedJson['image']
    );
  }
}
```

and the calling method:

```
Future<SliderModel> _loadSlider() async{
    try {
      Response response = await Dio().get("https://dasas/api/slider/");
      print("11111");   // printing 
      SliderModel slider = SliderModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.data));
      print("2222222222222");  // doesn't print throws error
      return slider;
    } catch (e) {
      print("error $e");
    }
  }
```

When I tried to run this codes it throws this message :

```
 type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If following line throws error that you mentioned then you don't need to json.decode it, as it is already a Map and not a JSON String.

```
SliderModel slider = SliderModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.data));
```

replace it with:

```
SliderModel slider = SliderModel.fromJson(response.data);
```

Let me know if it works for you, in case if it doesn't work please comment and if it does then don't forget to accept and up-vote the answer.

Comment: removed json.decode. now it throws this `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: So it worked.. The thing is in your JSON that you are receiving the count variable is int and in the slider model it is final String count; Change it to final int count and it will start working.. and if you want it in string then change count: parsedJson['count'], to count: parsedJson['count'].toString(),

Comment: removing json.decode was the right thing.. you were not receiving JSON string you were receiving JSONObject/Map. just make this change and it will work for you. I guess you have not reverted the change of removing json.decode, have you ??

Answer (score 2):

Look at this method:

```
factory SliderModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list = parsedJson['results'] as List;
    List<Result> imagesList = list.map((i) => Result.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return SliderModel(
      count: parsedJson['count'],
      results: imagesList
    );
  }
```

`list` is a list of dynamic ( List< dynamic >) . So after `.map` it's still List .

Solution: specify a return type for map.

```
List<Result> imagesList = list.map<Result>((i) => Result.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Comment: Changed the code as you suggested, still facing same error.

Comment: Are u sure the response from server is well-formated?